# How can this Java code compile without error?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, compilation, javac

Can someone explain why does this Java code compile?

```
public class Main {
     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println(foo(true));
        System.out.println(foo(false));
     }

     public static boolean foo(boolean value) {
         // this should make the compiler say something, at least complain a bit...
         return value ? true : null;
     }
}
```

Comment: Autoboxing.....

Comment: Have you looked through the JLS? Which rule do you think it's violating? This looks like it's covered by http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth But why does it then not compile when the ordering is reversed?

Comment: @milin - But it does compile :/

Comment: @JonSkeet I am unable to find any rule concerning the situation when 2nd operand is "boolean" and 3rd is "null", but I'm not sure that constitutes as "no rule is broken", rather I have a feeling like it was overlooked...

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth You are correct... Must have messed something up when I was trying it out...

Comment: Table 15.25-E covers this.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ups, you are correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Oliver said in the comments, the reason this *compiles* is autoboxing.

The `null` can be autoboxed into a `Boolean` which can be autounboxed to a `boolean`, making the compiler happy. At runtime the autoboxing works, but when it's unboxed to a `boolean` it will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: But why does it not compile when the ordering is reversed?

Comment: Which ordering?

Comment: As OliverCharlesworth mentioned above, I was wrong about this - it does compile!

Comment: Phew. I didn't want to start digging up some obscure rules about ternary operator autoboxing or something :)

Comment: Thank you for your effort! :) I understand now that the return type of the whole expression is derived from the operands, and then validated against the type that should hold the evaluated expression. I just can't shake off the feeling that this should fail, but I get why it doesn't...

Comment: But it _does_ fail, just not at compile time, as this answer explains.

Comment: `null` is assignable to `Boolean`, this part does _not_ involve autoboxing.

Comment: @StephanHerrmann There's no (explicit) `Boolean` in the whole code, only `boolean`. As I explained there's both boxing and unboxing happening for `null`, which makes the code compile.

Comment: @Kayaman, there's a lot of (implicit) `Boolean` in the picture. Autoboxing to `Boolean`, OTOH, requires a `boolean` value. `null` is not a `boolean` value. See my answer for the full story.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of conditional expression do we have ([JLS 15.25](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25))?

- Clearly not a numeric conditional expression.
- A boolean conditional expressions would require two operands of type `boolean`, which is violated by the 3rd operand being `null`
- Ergo we have a [reference conditional expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25.3)

For reference conditional expressions Table [15.25-E](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25-400-E) specifies that a combination of boolean (2nd) and null (3rd) determines the full expression to have type `lub(Boolean,null)`

For runtime evaluation this sentence provides the desired clarity:

> At run time, the first operand expression of the conditional expression is evaluated first. If necessary, unboxing conversion is performed on the result.

Depending on the first operand, one of the following happens:

- `true` is autoboxed to `Boolean`, *or*
- `null` is taken, which is already compatible to `Boolean` (based on [JLS-4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1)) (*this is not autoboxing as claimed by the other answer*)

The resulting `Boolean` will be autounboxed, which in the second case will throw `NullPointerException`.